# cant run the controller with symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I generated my bundle with netbeans with no error , then went to my main config file in the app directory and set this:

```
first_app:
resource: "@FirstAppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

Then set this in my bundle routing.yml file:

```
first_app_homepage:
pattern:  /hello/{name}
defaults: { _controller: FirstAppBundle:Hello:index }
```

I have got this controller:

```
namespace DimaVendor\MytestsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction($name) {
        return new Response('<html><body>' . $name . '</body></html>');
    }



}
```

I get 404 when I go to there:

```
http://localhost/app.php/hello/Ryan
```

why?

I also cleaned my cache and found no error

Comment: Did you install your symfony app in webserver root or in any subfolder?

Comment: in project1..this is how netbeans creates them ...puts everything in a subfolder

Comment: even this wouldnt work: http://localhost/PhpProject1/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan

Comment: Point your browser to [http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan](http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan) then.

Comment: interesting ,, you put the word web before app_dev and it worked..why?

Comment: Because `app_dev.php` script lies in `web/` subfolder of your project - browse and figure on your own!

Comment: lol..I know, but it should do it automatically without the web keyword.. like the official docs say

Comment: [Read carefully](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html).

Comment: can you post your answer and i will accept it. Also is there a way to use htaccess in the directory to make them appear normal? some global htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.php` and `app_dev.php` scripts are the entry points for Symfony apps, and they lie in `web/` subfolder in the project - in this case, point your browser to:

`http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan`

`.htaccess` comes in `web/` folder, and redirects any requests to:

```
http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/some/path
```

to:

```
http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/app.php/some/path
```

in your case. Have a look!