# How to set default controller and action in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

How can I set default controller and action in symfony2. Where to configure this settings.

Comment: You need to explain your question in a little more detailed way. Default controller/action as in exactly what sense?

Comment: Do you mean [How to create pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html)? or [How to reroute all routes to an action](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19248102/1607098) ?

Answer (score 4):

Which annotation do you use?

My default Route is in the file app/config/routing.yml

```
_index:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ACMEUserBundle:Default:index }
```

If you have installed with DemoBundle there is a Default Route in the file `src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`.

Comment: For those having the "DefaultController does not exist" Exception (after renaming DefaultController). Don't forget the actual controller's name is the Class name and not the file name.

Answer (score 1):

**Look the Link it's show some idea to you**
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html
[cant run the controller with symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448806/cant-run-the-controller-with-symfony-2)